# Passing props to Outlet when nesting so I could use componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Im using react-router-v6 and I have problems with my setup. I'm using nested routing with layouts with following settings.

**App.js**

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>     
        <Route exact path='/' element={<SiteLayout />} />
      </Routes>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/app/' element={<AppLayout />} >
          <Route path='dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} />
          <Route path='send' element={<Send />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

AppLayout is a class element and have some state variables and data fetching im passing to Dashboard component through `<Outlet />` using context at the moment. This works fine but the Dashboard component should be able to do its own rest call using data passed from AppLayout when new data arrives. This I was planning to do with componentDidUpdate in Dashboard component but what i understood it does not work with context? So every time I pass context to Dashboard it does not fetch data and does not update. How could i continue from here? Im tearing my hair here atm :D trying to figure how to work with this. Is there some other way to automatically run a function when class component gets new data?

Comment: Can you update your question to include all relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? You've shared the router and routes but it sounds like your question is really about passing data from `AppLayout` to the `Dashboard` component. We can't help debug code we can't see.

Comment: @DrewReese Sorry I forgot to mention earlier that i solved this problem by using context in passing data so did not have to use <Outlet />.

Comment: In case you didn't know, `Outlet` also provides a Context. [`useOutletContext`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useoutletcontext).

Answer (score 0):

just do this instead.

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>     
        <Route exact path='/' element={<SiteLayout />} />
        <Route path='/app/' element={<AppLayout />} />
        <Route path='/app/dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path='/app/dashboard/send' element={<Send />} />
      </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out but id like to have the AppLayout used by the Dashboard and Send as layout :) Not sure though that helps with passing props to `<Outlet />`? I can pass the props from App.js just to putting it inside component in element tag (`element={<Dashboard myProps=someProps}`) but I would not wan't to move lots of states etc. from AppLayout component which has the Dashboard and Send as children. There is also one dropdown in AppLayout that sends data to its children.